# Error during template rendering

Tags: django

I am new to django, now following django tutorial part 4(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial04/), I am stuck with the error in detail.html.

### detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}"/>
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

It says, the error "argument to reversed() must be a sequence" in "{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}".

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = {
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
}
```

### views.py

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace='polls')),
]
```

Comment: Sharing your urls.py will be helpful to answer.

Comment: Most likely the error is in your views.py; where you forgot to add a comma after `p.id`, in this line: `reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,))` (the comma makes it a tuple).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I have checked the code, comma is not forgotten. And I have updated the question, have a look please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In urls.py of application,

```
urlpatterns = {...}
```

should be

```
urlpatterns = [...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you define the 'polls' namespace correctly in your root url's like this?

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

change this line

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

to

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', kwargs={'pk':p.id}))
```

Comment: It doesn't work, bro. I try http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/, this will load index.html, a same error occur. T T... I might take a rest, go back tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use named arguments for your links, like :

```
{% url 'polls:vote' question_id=question.id %}
```

or in the view :

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', kwargs={'pk': p.pk}))
```

Comment: kwargs={'pk'=p.pk}, I am told which is invalid syntax. And I tried {% url 'polls:vote' question_id=question.id %}, the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I did it without trying... Of course, it is a ":" and not a "=" in the kwargs. I correct it in the response right now.